# gcc -L command confusion

Tags: c++, gcc

Let's say I have a shared library file, `libdemo.so`, where `libdemo.so` is the final linker.

If I want to build the executable, and if the library file is in the current working directory, I link it in with the `-L. -ldemo` flags.

But when I run the executable, unless I specify the library path, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.`, the executable can't find the link. So why the need for the extra `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting? The flags are for the link-time library path and the environment variable is the run-time library path supposedly.

Alternatively, if I build the executable and specify a run-time library path using `-Wl,-rpath,.` I can omit `-L. -ldemo`.

I know this has to do with link-time and run-time but I am unclear on what the difference is. For instance, when not using `-rpath`, what does the `-L. -ldemo` actually do if the executable needs `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find the library file? And when using the latter method, if specifying `-rpath` means copying the directory location into the run-time library path, why does this also allow the `-L. -ldemo` to be omitted?

If the link-time library path and run-time library path are different, how come the latter method doesn't need the link-time library path when building? What is the difference between a link-time library path and run-time library path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research (reading a textbook), I found the answer I was looking for.

Basically, since the executable file no longer contains copies of the object files, it needs some way to identify the shared library that it needs. During the link phase, the name of the shared library is embedded in the executable, but the specific location is not yet specified. So the `-L. -ldemo` is really just to provide the name of the library file. Note that in the question, I say that `-L. -ldemo` was not specified when setting the `-rpath`. That is because in that command I had actually passed the name of the library directly, `libdemo.so`. If I had not done so specifying it with `-L. -ldemo` was necessary.

The run-time library path is subsequently provided to specify the exact location at the time of execution.

Answer (score 3):

Because linking is done by two different instances of Linker.

When you compile & link your program, linker like `/usr/bin/ld` checks external references and builds your executable adding external reference `libdemo.so`.

When you run your program, run-time linker `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (or generally say `ld.so`) loads all needed *shared objects*. There are several reasons `-L` is not saved:

- it is not necessary that `libdemo.so` is located at the same path it was during compiling (because you could copy your binary onto another host, that path was internal build path, etc.)
- it may be unsafe, so `ld.so` ususally seeks over list of "trusted" paths where non-root users couldn't write

However, there were some cases when saving `-L` would be useful (i.e. software installed into `/opt`) , so **some** of Unixes introduced RPATH.